# What's the difference between |, > and >- in OpenAPI YAML descriptions?

Tags: yaml, openapi

I'm looking at OpenAPI and the `description` tag. What are the differences between these tags? They all support multiple lines, but anything else?

```
description: |
description: >
description: >-
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`description` isn't a YAML "tag", it's just a field/property in the YAML file you're editing, such as an OpenAPI or Swagger document.

The YAML specification describes the different text folding styles here: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2793652

That's pretty hard to understand at first glance, so this site makes things a lot easier, and has interactive examples: https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: I saw both of those sites. The yaml-multiline one is very good. However, using Redocly, those conventions don't work the same way. I was wondering if it is a bug in Redocly, or there are flavors that change on each platform.

Comment: What specifically doesn't work in ReDoc? It may be the fault of the YAML parser they are using.

Answer (score 4):

`|`, `>`, `>-` are some of YAML [block style](https://yaml-multiline.info/) indicators. They are used to break a long string value over multiple lines and format multi-paragraphs Markdown strings. You can find more information here:

- https://yaml-multiline.info/
- [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3790454/113116)

In OpenAPI context, the use of `>` vs `|` in descriptions affects the resulting Markdown rendering.

#### `>` (folded style)

This replaces single new lines with spaces, but adds a new line at the end of the YAML value. To have a literal new line in the value, add a blank line between the lines. To start a new Markdown paragraph, add *two* blank lines between the paragraphs.

For example:

```yaml
description: >
  Quick
  brown fox

  jumps over a lazy dog.


  And this is a new paragraph.
```

This means the `description` value is:

[image]

which after being processed with a Markdown renderer becomes:

```html
<p>Quick brown fox<br/>
jumps over a lazy dog.</p>

<p>And this is a new paragraph.</p>
```

#### `>-` (folded style with the strip block chomping indicator)

Same as `>` but with no new line at the end of the YAML value.

Markdown renderers don't care about the trailing new line, so the `>` and `>-` styles are rendered exactly the same.

#### `|` (literal style)

New lines in the YAML value are kept as is. For example:

```yaml
description: >
  Quick
  brown fox

  jumps over a lazy dog.


  And this is a new paragraph.
```

This means the `description` value is:

[image]

which will be rendered as

```html
<p>Quick<br>
brown fox</p>

<p>jumps over a lazy dog.</p>

<p>And this is a new paragraph.</p>
```