# What does ">-" do?

Tags: yaml

I have found some internal async-api schema that looks like the following example:

```yaml
  schemas:
    Example:
      type: object
      allOf:
        - $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
        - type: object
          properties:
            bar:
              type: string
              description: >-
                Some description
```

What does the `>-` mean in this case? I could not find any documentation about this. The [official specification](https://github.com/asyncapi/spec/blob/master/spec/asyncapi.md) only mentions the `|` character, which indicates a multiline string.

Comment: It's not part of the AsyncAPI spec, just basic YAML - https://yaml-multiline.info/

Comment: See also [What's the difference between |, > and >- in OpenAPI YAML descriptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67377832/113116) (it applies to both OpenAPI and AsyncAPI).

Comment: It is one of the many many YAML string formatting options. See [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines)

Comment: Thank you for the quick responses. I was only searching for "async-api multiline strings" and "swagger multiline strings", that's why I did not find anything. But it makes sense, since it is in the yaml-specification and not swagger- or async-api specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`|` and `>` are both used for multiline strings.

> **Block Style Indicator**: The block style indicates how newlines inside the block should behave. If you would like them to be kept as
> newlines, use the **literal** style, indicated by a pipe (`|`). If instead
> you want them to be replaced by spaces, use the **folded** style,
> indicated by a right angle bracket (`>`). (To get a newline using the
> folded style, leave a blank line by putting two newlines in. Lines
> with extra indentation are also not folded.)
>
> **Block Chomping Indicator**: The chomping indicator controls what should happen with newlines at the end of the string. The default,
> **clip**, puts a single newline at the end of the string. To remove all
> newlines, **strip** them by putting a minus sign (`-`) after the style
> indicator. Both clip and strip ignore how many newlines are actually
> at the end of the block; to **keep** them all put a plus sign (`+`) after
> the style indicator.

Source with interactivity, so you can easily see the differences between these syntaxes: https://yaml-multiline.info/

See also [How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21699210/9847511) for an in-depth explanation.